# PostgreSQL ST_Intersects dynamic coordinate using WITH and VALUES

Tags: postgresql, performance

I need to intersect a specific point with a polygon map.
For that purpose I'm defining my variables using the WITH statement on top of the query. However I've noticed the if I "hard-code" the POINT, the query takes 400ms, and if I defined using the WITH statement, the running time increases to 15 seconds.

Could anyone help me to sort it out why is this happening?

**This one takes 15 seconds**

```
WITH 
     "my_variables" (v_gps) AS
     (VALUES ('-9.167162 38.738757'))

    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON ("11_map_all_shp".map_id)
        "11_map_all_shp".map_id,
        "11_map_all_shp".geom
    FROM
        "11_map_all_shp",
        "my_variables"
    WHERE
        ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || v_gps || ')',4326)) 
    ORDER BY
        "11_map_all_shp".map_id ASC,
        "11_map_all_shp".precedence ASC
```

**This one takes 400ms**

```
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON ("11_map_all_shp".map_id)
        "11_map_all_shp".map_id,
        "11_map_all_shp".geom
    FROM
        "11_map_all_shp"
    WHERE
        ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-9.167162 38.738757)',4326)) 
    ORDER BY
        "11_map_all_shp".map_id ASC,
        "11_map_all_shp".precedence ASC
```

Comment: I'm guessing that PG can optimize the 2nd query to hit an index, but isn't able to do this for the 1st one because of the join (which your `WITH` query is doing). Have you tried comparing the query plan for both using `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`? I'd also be interested to know if building the `geometry` in the "my_variables" part of the 1st query (rather than the `WHERE`) makes any difference (ie. use `WITH "my_variables" (v_gps) AS (VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-9.167162 38.738757)')))`?

Comment: Unfortunately building the `geometry` in the "my_variables" makes no difference on the performance. However the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` give me useful tips on what's causing the issue. For now I still found a solution, but at least I have information how to sort it out. Prints of the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-q0ImP7ipjE2ca19rPaJUnRgYzYr1uhG/view?usp=sharing). Thank you.

Comment: For now, I end up to change the full solution, and hardcoded the variables inside the query. Nevertheless if someone finds a solution, please let me know.

Comment: I've had a quick look at the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` output you've provided; you can see the CTE is run very late in the piece as a nested loops join. Essentially no indexes have been hit at this point so it's doing a full walk of your `11_map_all_shp` table and comparing each one with the list from the CTE. I suspect if you `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` the 2nd query, you'll find that it's able to hitting an index in the early part of the query plan. The CTE & join complicates this since the query optimiser isn't smart enough to know that there is only 1 record on the `my_variables` side of the join.